# Copy specific cells from a row to specific cells on another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a `player` database. Each `player` has their own row with some of the data I collect. Once I add a new row for a new `player`, I have a script set up that will create a formatted sheet for each new `player` in the same workbook and give it a name based on the `Name` column.

How do I get certain cells from their row and copy them to a set destination on their unique `player` sheet?

For example:

> Col A: player ID | Col B: Name | Col C: email |

Once this new player is added on the `Database` sheet, a new sheet will be created with their `Name`. How do I copy the info in their row to specific cells in the `Name` sheet (In the `Name` sheet, `player ID` goes to `C3`, `Name` goes to `C4`, `email` goes to `D5`)?

Here's what I have so far but don't know how to copy data in the new row to specific cells of the new sheet:

```js
function addFormattedSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var rData = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues();
  
  var templateCopy = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  
  if (row == 1) {
    ss.toast("This is the header");    
    return //This sends the user an error if the first row is selected when the script is activated
  }

  if(rData[0][0] != null || rData[0][1] != null || rData[0][2] != null) {
    try {
      ss.insertSheet(rData[0][2], {template: templateCopy}); //Creates the new sheet
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); //sets the first roster sheet as the active sheet
      //Not sure what this does:
      sh.getRange("D"+(row)).setValue(new Date());
    } catch(e) {
      throw 'This player already exists.';      
    }
  }
}
```